# I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error on Nginx when trying to proxy pass to localhost

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a setup for local development, where my backend API server running on `localhost:5000` and the frontend NextJS server on `localhost:3000`.
Both of these servers work just fine when accessing them directly through `localhost:5000` and `localhost:3000` respectively, but I wanted to simulate these servers being accessed through the domain names `api.product.com` and `app.product.com` respectively, for the purposes of local development.

I added the following to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   api.product.com app.product.com
```

I also configured `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to be:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.product.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.product.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
  }
}

events {}
```

However, when the nginx server is running (`sudo systemctl start nginx`) and I access `api.product.com` or `app.product.com`, nginx throws up a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

Why is this? How do I fix it?

EDIT:
I had a look at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and it was saying `failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream`. I then did a bit of digging and discovered that this was because of SELinux (I'm running Fedora). I checked SELinux logs with `sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied` and sure enough, it was SELinux. I then ran `audit2why` and it recommended that I run `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` to resolve this permission issue, and after that it worked